# How to use pure CSS to show an animation of one element's background and color property?

Tags: css

I want to see whether it's possible to do this:

```
$('.hello').addClass('hint-auto-fade');
```

I hope the class `.hint-auto-fade` can be something like add a background of `#ffe` and color of `#f00` to the `.hello` elements and fade away in 5 or 10 seconds. The elements then go back to its former background/color property (if has).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
$('.hello').addClass('hint-auto-fade');
```

```css
.hello {
  color: blue;
}

.hint-auto-fade {
  animation: autoFade 5s linear;
}

@keyframes autoFade {
  from {
    background: #ffe;
    color: #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hello">
  Hello
</div>

<hr>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. <span class="hello">Phasellus consequat gravida arcu vulputate rutrum. Phasellus efficitur ante ac quam dapibus mollis.</span> Donec libero quam, sollicitudin in semper sed, interdum at nulla.
</p>
```

Comment: It must be a lag of my internet. I up-voted and accepted your answer right after posting that comment. now it's done! thanks again!